# WebMethod (sometimes) returns entire website

Tags: asp.net, webmethod

I have a WebMethod which accepts one parameter.

When I send a request to the webmethod without any parameters everything works well but when I supply a parameter to the same method, it returns entire site instead of a string.

The page parameter changes nothing except the content of the list.

List is just ListView which displays list of strings.

When I use URLRewriting the URL is different in instances that I supply a parameter from instances when I do not.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

My WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]  
public static string GetResult(int id)  
{
    return "Hooray";
}
```

My web method call:

```
PageMethods.GetResult(docId,  
    function onSuccess(list) {  
        $(element).parent().siblings().filter(":first").append(list);  
    });
```

URL without parameter:
`www.mywebsite.com/items is rewritten to www.mywebsite.com/items.aspx`

URL with parameter:
`www.mywebsite.com/items/1 is rewritten to www.mywebsite.com/items.aspx?id=1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [a discussion about your same issue](http://forums.asp.net/t/1312021.aspx/1) that might shed some light on the situation. Basically, what it says is that it's not working because the handler that deals with PageMethods is looking for {pagename.aspx}/{methodname}, and your url rewriting is causing it to not recognize you are calling a page method.

One suggestion on that page was to add the following in your javascript code somewhere after the auto-generated call of the same signature:

```
PageMethods.set_path('/items.aspx');
```

This will make it call your page method using the real url instead of the rewritten one.

Comment: Thanks alot! It worked. The only thing i had to add to your solution was to add root url. I use  `var url = window.location.href;  
    var baseUrl = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('/', 24));
    PageMethods.set_path(baseUrl + '/item.aspx');`

Comment: You just saved me after 24hrs of frustration. Thanks buddy!