# asp.net page method from javascript doesn't fire if I leave the page and return

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, pagemethods

I have an asp.net web forms app where I'm calling a c# code behind method from javascript using PageMethods. This works fine at first, but if I navigate to a different page and then return and trigger the method, the code behind method is not called. The onSuccess method still runs, but the method in code behind is never called. I'm at a loss here, could really use some help. Thanks!

Javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnLinkEmployee", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    var lbEmpHidden = document.getElementById('<%= lbEmpIdHidden.ClientID %>');
    lbEmpHidden.value = id;

    PageMethods.GetAvailableUsers(onSuccess, onError);
    function onSuccess(result) {
        var radWindow = $find("<%= rwLinkEmployee.ClientID %>");
        radWindow.show();
        var resultArr = JSON.parse(result);
        var rcb = $find("<%= rcbAvailUsers.ClientID %>");
        for (var i = 0; i < resultArr.length; i++) {
            var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
            comboItem.set_text(resultArr[i].UserName);
            comboItem.set_value(resultArr[i].Id);
            rcb.get_items().add(comboItem);
        }
    }
    function onError(result) {
        alert(result);
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

C#

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetAvailableUsers()
{
    using(var context = new TTEntities())
    {
        var allUsers = context.AspNetUsers.ToList();
        List<AspNetUser> users = new List<AspNetUser>();
        foreach(AspNetUser user in allUsers)
        {
            var result = context.Employees.Where(b => b.UserId == user.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            if(result == null)
            {
                users.Add(user);
            }
        }

        var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = js.Serialize(users);
        return json;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you returning to the page? A `Response.Redirect` or another way? Is there some code that modifies the page somehow on page load when you're returning to the page?

Comment: I'm just navigating to a different page view the menu. All pages are child pages of a master page. There is no redirect or anything that would modify the page to my knowledge. @krlzlx

Comment: @krlzlx An update.. the return value in onSuccess looks like it's the entire document.. weird.

Comment: For anyone trying to solve this problem, found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427502/webmethod-sometimes-returns-entire-website

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the feedback.